# Django _view_() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django

I have faced a problem with my django project. 
It is as following: I had a simple regexp to match the users

```
url(r'^users/\w+/$', views.user)
```

And it worked perfectly.

Then I changed the regexpt, because there was an update in users' logins, so now it is (I added the dot symbol):

```
url(r'^users/([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)/$', views.user)
```

And now I am getting the "user() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" django error.

The view is defined like this:

```
def user(request):
    return render(request, 'home/user_page.html')
```

Comment: Don't you ever use the varying part of the URL (`[a-zA-Z0-9.]+`) in your code? To query the database or something?

Answer (score 10):

As stated in the error message, your view needs to take a second parameter:

```
def user(request, second_param):
    return render(request, 'home/user_page.html')
```

This is because you added a group in the regex (the part between parenthesis) and Django passes any matched group as arguments to the view.

If you prefer the previous behaviour, remove the parenthesis from your regex:

```
r'^users/[a-zA-Z0-9.]+/$'
```

Relevant documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request